# Delete numbers and punctuation with preg_replace PHP

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I want to erase numbers and punctuation (full stops, commas, etc) of a string in PHP, I tried this for example

```
<?php
 $str = "Hello, lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet. Adipiscing90 elit. 1234567890. ";
 $text = preg_replace('/\d+/u', '', $str);
 echo $text;
?>
```

This only delete numbers but no punctuation resulting this:

> Hello, lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet. Adipiscing elit. .

I want to get like this, with no commas, full stops, etc:

> Hello lorem ipsum dolor sit amet Adipiscing elit

How can I modify preg_replace function?

I would like some help.

Comment: Try the pattern `/[^\w\s]|\d/`.

Comment: So just keep letters and spaces? https://regex101.com/r/DeRxeD/2/

Comment: /[[:punct:]]|\d/ matches punctuation and digits

Comment: @miknik You won't need the alteration, just put the `\d` in the character class as well. `[[:punct:]\d]+`.

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton  it works great! Thanks!

Comment: @chris85 it works great! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There are `[:punct:]` POSIX character class and [`\p{P}`](https://regex101.com/r/8W6mbB/2) Unicode property/category class to match *punctuation*, but note that they are not equal. [`[:punct:]`](https://regex101.com/r/8W6mbB/3) can also match all *symbols*, and in fact, `[:punct:]` = [`[\p{P}\p{S}]`](https://regex101.com/r/8W6mbB/4).

So, based on your requirements, either use

```
preg_replace('/[\d\p{P}]+/u', '', $str)
```

or

```
preg_replace('/[\d[:punct:]]+/u', '', $str)
```

You may check which characters belong to each category at [FileFormat.info](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/index.htm).

Answer (score 0):

```
preg_replace('/[\d\p{P}]/', '', $str)
```

output is "Hello lorem ipsum dolor sit amet Adipiscing elit  "